# Calculating P-value for multivariate normal distributions?

Tags: normal-distribution, p-value, multivariate-normal-distribution, z-score, scipy

I'm given a set of 500 ($\sigma_i, \mu_i$) that define a 500-dimensional multivariate normal distribution, where each dimension is effectively independent from all the others.

Given a 500-dimensional vector $\vec{x}$, how can I calculate its two-sided p-value for a given z-score (say, 3 sigmas)?

Can I simply do something like:

```
2 * (1 - scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.cdf(x, mean=mu, cov=np.diag(std)))
```

in Scipy, where `mu` and `std` are 500-dimensional Numpy arrays with the $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$?

Comment: "Two-sided" does not apply to distributions with more than 2 dimensions. You would need to (numerically) integrate the CDF to get the a p-value for a given z-score. I don't know Python but there should be a function to calculate the quantiles, I know there is one in R.

Comment: Thanks @user2974951, but why wouldn't it apply? As my 500 random variables are *independent*, the multivariate distribution is should be equivalent to the product of 500 univariate gaussians, shouldn't it? If so, "two-sided" still makes sense.

Comment: This might be related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331283/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-a-data-point-belonging-to-a-multivariate-nor